# Use client to access database or server to access database

Tags: python, database

I' creating a client server application in which I need to update a particular database. I'm using python with MySQL.

The client.py file will be reading a QRcode and sending data enclosed which is to be stored on the database. There are about 50 such clients which will be sending data to the server.

I've setup a MySQL server on the server, and already created tables for each client.

There are two options to manipulate the database on the server:

The client accesses databases and queries directly with the MySQL server.

The internet says everything about accessing MySQL records, and I can accomplish that using the following code:

**client.py**

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

con = None

try:

    con = mdb.connect('server_address', 'user', 
        'pass', 'table pertaining to that particular client');

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

    data = cur.fetchone()

    print "Database version : %s " % data

except mdb.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:    

    if con:    
        con.close()
```

or I can create a server.py file, that will get data in the form of JSON, and itself handle the database on localhost.

Which method is better?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: @MartijnPieters How can I make it more specific or should I redirect it to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1) ?

Comment: I'd say this is a Whiteboard-type problem, so Programmers would be a better place. However, you need to provide (much) more detail here, like the type of program this is, what problems you have encountered, etc. There are way too many variables involved otherwise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There are no variables involved till now, how can I move it to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1) ?

Comment: I fear it'll be closed as NC or NARQ because you need to show at least some research effort here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've edited the question and included everything I know till now.

Comment: Having a table per client sounds like a bad idea. You would very likely be better off with a single table, with a column for a client identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best" answer, only trade-offs.

Using direct MySQL connections makes programming simpler and faster (less layers), but can make the system brittle to change.

If you go client/server (over TCP or HTTP), it's easier to secure (no DB creds on the client, no need to expose the MySQL server to the client), easier to change down the road (you can change the table without changing the client.)